# Relative links on a custom 404 page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a personalized 404 error page in my web, with

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.htm
```

in my `.htaccess`.

The problem is, if you type `www.mydomain.com/whatever/whatever2.html`, it shows the 404 page correctly, but the links are all broken, for example a link to `href="property.php"` points to `www.mydomain.com/whatever/property.php`, that is a 404 error too.

How can I fix this without changing all the routes to absolute routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was searching for :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using relative paths like:

```
href="property.php"
```

Try using absolute paths like:

```
href="http://www.example.com/path/to/property.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <base href="/">
```

does not work with google Adsense/Analytics. Division zero.

Because the Error 404 page has to be able to run from any URL my 404.php simply contains

```
<?php
header("Location: http:/homepage.de");
?>
```

This way it relocates to the base URL.